# bash: using sed to replace end of line between substring

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to do something relatively simple but I am not sure how to do it.

I have a mac address as follows:

```
xx:yy:yy:zz:yy:yy
```

I would like to modify the :yy: at the end of the string so that it becomes :01:
Using our example above, it becomes:

```
xx:yy:yy:zz:01:yy
```

Basically the characters between the last : : in the string.

I was trying the following but it wasn't working:

```
echo "$var" | sed 's/:*:*$/:01:/'
```

I know this is a simple question, but any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: `*` is a glob pattern.  You want the regex equivalent `.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk is easier to solve this kind of problem:

```
awk -F: -v OFS=":" '$5="01"'
```

example:

```
kent$  echo "xx:yy:yy:zz:yy:yy"|awk -F: -v OFS=":" '$5="01"'
xx:yy:yy:zz:01:yy
```

Comment: @Pumbaa80 have you read the question before you downvote? OP said it is Mac address.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have two characters after the last :, the answer is:

```
echo xx:yy:yy:zz:yy:yy | sed 's/\(.*:\).*\(:..\)$/\101\2/'
```

If you think my assumption is wrong, I can improve on it.

Comment: Improved: `sed -r 's/:[^:]+:([^:]*)$/:01:\1/'`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "$var" | sed 's/[^:]*/01/5'
```

Comment: or perhaps `sed 's/[^:]*/01/5' <<<"$var"`

Answer (score 0):

jthills answer was good u need to put .* instead of * also the $ In my bash (try man bash) I get errors using the $ because I think the parse of user input is tring to match the $ to a parameter (eg $0 $1 $2) rather than the end key in regrex. Try deleting the $ anchor to the end of the line. Regexcrosswords.com has a help that helped me a bit.

You may a benefit from knowning that the sed -e is for a script and the `'s///'` specifies the script but it can also be `'s_f_r_;/f/r/; ... \/find\/replace\/'` or this means demittted by underscores_ slashes or `\/` forwardslash+backslash.

I have not yet found a method for searching for parenthesis characters.